# Bearer token that never expires

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api2, bearer-token

Is it possible define that ASP.NET Web API 2 bearer token that never expires? Any clue?

Comment: ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET Web API are different projects.

Comment: You can set expiration to 1 year or 100.

Comment: that's a really bad idea! If you have an access token which never expires, how is it different than a password/username combination? It's even worse than that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can set it to never expire but you could certainly set a longer `AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan`:

```
OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
{
    TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
    Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId, UserManagerFactory),
    AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
    AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
    AllowInsecureHttp = true
};  
app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);
```

Answer (score 7):

I think we can also achieve this by using given below code

```
AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.MaxValue
```

According to MSDN,

**The value of this field is equivalent to Int64.MaxValue ticks. The string representation of this value is positive 10675199.02:48:05.4775807, or slightly more than 10,675,199 days https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.maxvalue(v=vs.110).aspx**