# Generate Token in IdentityServer4 that never expires

Tags: authentication, identityserver4, restful-authentication, jwt

I have an application (ASP.Net Core 2.2, IdentityServer4) which is working fine. Now I need to authenticate some devices or applications in my application to let them call my APIs.

I've read these links:

[IdentityServer4 Access Token Lifetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50363450/identityserver4-access-token-lifetime)

[Bearer token that never expires](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22309465/bearer-token-that-never-expires)

but these are not something that I need.

I need to make some kind of authentication that never expires and I just expire that manually. What is the correct solution? Any Ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can use [Reference Tokens](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/reference_tokens.html), not to be mistaken by Refresh Tokens.

From the documentation:

> When using reference tokens - IdentityServer will store the contents
>   of the token in a data store and will only issue a unique identifier
>   for this token back to the client. The API receiving this reference
>   must then open a back-channel communication to IdentityServer to
>   validate the token.

So the reference is only a reference. It contains no information about security or expiration. The referenced information is stored in the data store and is only accessable by the resource that receives the reference token, using back-channel communication. The reference remains valid until it is removed from the data store (token is revoked).

In order to make this work you should use [AddIdentityServerAuthentication](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/apis.html#the-identityserver-authentication-handler) in the client and api for handling and validating reference tokens. You can configure the client to use reference tokens as follows (as documented):

```
client.AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Reference;
```

The documentation also mentions a secret for the api.